# Рассчитать первоначальное количество рублей, при заданных условиях

Tags: математика, арифметика

Помогите найти математическую формулу, которая позволяет всегда получать правильный ответ при разных исходных данных. Нужно для гугл таблиц, поэтому можно использовать встроенные формулы Гугл.

Задача:

У меня есть какое-то первоначальное количество рублей, скажем X

На 20% от X я купил доллары по 90 руб за штуку
На 30% от X я купил доллары по 80 руб за штуку
На 50% от X я купил доллары по 70 руб за штуку

Но цена опустилась до 60 руб и я решил продать все доллары себе в убыток, при этом я потерял 5000 руб от первоначальных вложений (X).

Цель:

1. Математически вычислить сколько у меня было рублей в самом начале.
2. Свести все вычисления в одну конечную формулу (если возможно).
3. В конечной формуле не должно присутствовать другие неизвестные, только результат в виде числа.
4. Проверить, что результат вычисления соответствует проверке.

Проверка:

1. Из полученного X рублей берём 20% и на них покупаем доллары по 90 руб.
2. Из полученного X рублей берём 30% и на них покупаем доллары по 80 руб.
3. Из полученного X рублей берём 50% и на них покупаем доллары по 70 руб.
4. Суммируя все купленные доллары и у нас получается количество N долларов.
5. Теперь если от X первоначального количества рублей отнять количество N долларов умноженное на цену моей продажи в 60 рублей за доллар и прибавить убыток в 5000 рублей, то должно получиться первоначальное количество рублей X

Формула проверки будет выглядеть так :

X - N * 60 + 5000 = X

Или так:

X - (X * 20% / 90 + X * 30% / 80 + X * 50% / 70) * 60 + 5000 = X

или так:

X = X - (X * 0,2 / 90 + X * 0,3 / 80 + X * 0,5 / 70) * 60 + 5000

Когда в результате проверки соблюдается условие X = X , то проверка считается пройденной. Также допускается расхождения на сотую часть рубля.

P.S. Сначала ошибся в написании формулы проверки, за что спасибо знатокам форума, быстро заметили, поэтому я исправил формулу.

Comment: Знатоки есть, постановки задачи нет...

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов  Честно, не вижу странного в исправленной формуле проверки. Первый раз я действительно ошибся, так как в формуле пропустил деление на курсы долларов. Но потом прочитал ваше первое сообщение и исправил. В целом, задача полностью решена благодаря знатоку MBo причём даже с моей первоначальной ошибкой.

Comment: Скажите, зависит ли сумма, на которую продали доллары ( N ) от размера начального капитала ( X )?  А потом найдите N  из Вашей формулы ```X - N * 60 + 5000 = X```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну что за детский сад...

```
X*(0.2/90+0.3/80+0.5/70)*60 = X-5000
(0.2/90+0.3/80+0.5/70)*60 = 1 - 5000/X
5000/X = 1 - (0.2/90+0.3/80+0.5/70)*60
X = 5000 / (1 - (0.2/90+0.3/80+0.5/70)*60)  = 23463.68715
```

Или формулой:

```
StartSum = Loss / (1 - BadPrice * Sum(Part[i] / Price[i]))
```

Comment: Вы думаете, вам тут же не зададут вопрос "а если я покупать буду четырьмя частями? а если будет 22%?" и так далее? По постановке задачи очевидно, что самой задачи по сути нет...

Comment: @Harry Ну может быть, получится обобщить...

Comment: @MBo Очень благодарю за быстрый ответ. Даже не ожидал такого чуда, причём в самом начале в формуле проверки допустил ошибку и не смотря на это вы всё равно дали решение. Прямо камень с плеч свалился. Третий полный день мучаюсь с этим вопросом и мучал ИИ chatGPT, который всё время хитрил и давал неправильные результаты. В общем, благодарю ещё раз и знал бы как отблагодарить материально - сделал бы это.

Comment: @Алексей "ИИ chatGPT, который всё время хитрил и давал неправильные результаты" - проблема с ChatGPT в том, что это не ИИ. Он может быть и искусственный, но точно не интеллект.